# since i don't have access tp PGsql server but I have access of PGadmin so is there any way i can connect PGADMIN to Liquibase

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql, liquibase-pro

since I do not have access of the PGSQL server because of sensitive data but I have access of the "PGadmin" is there any way I can connect "Liquibase" to PGadmin and any change in change-log file triggers "Liquibase Update" and then PGadmin triggers the server for changes

Answer (score 0):

you will need the database url, user and password in order to connect to the liquibase. You can find how to set up the connection using liquibase.properties file here: https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html

Comment: Thanks for reply let me try that method also